# Are there meaningful statements about the numbers which cannot be proved with Peano+(independence from Peano)

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

There are meaningful statements about the natural numbers not provable in Peano.  Can all such statements be proven by Peano+(Their independence from Peano).

For example can Strengthened Finite Ramsey Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem#The_strengthened_finite_Ramsey_theorem be proven using only Peano+(the independence of Strengthened Finite Ramsey Theorem from Peano), and if so, are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Note that "the Paris-Harrington theorem" is the name of the _metatheorem_, not of the sentence that the metatheorem states that PA cannot prove.

Comment: I think what you have in mind is not the independence of the Paris-Harrington Thm. (from Peano arithmetic), but rather the independence of the underlying first-order arithmetic proposition mentioned by the Paris-Harrington Thm., namely the [strengthened finite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem#The_strengthened_finite_Ramsey_theorem).

Comment: @hardmath yes I'm sure you're right. I will fix.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, regardless of what $P$ is, the sentence "$P$ is independent from PA" is a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence; so any sentence $P$ which is independent from PA *and not provable from PA + any true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence* will be an example. One important class of such statements are *reflection* (or *soundness*) *principles*: these roughly assert that PA proves only true things,  and surprisingly are not provable in PA alone (see e.g. Lob's theorem)! E.g. I believe even $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection ("all $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences provable in PA are true") is already not provable from PA + $Th_{\Pi^0_1}(\mathbb{N})$.

Note that $\Sigma_1^0$-reflection and the like are indeed expressible in the language of arithmetic via appropriate Goedelian arguments (and in particular, they refer only to *bounded truth predicates*, so Tarski's undefinability theorem doesn't apply); by contrast, of course, *full* reflection is inexpressible (roughly, $\Sigma^0_n$-reflection is a $\Pi^0_{n+1}$-sentence, so as you want "more" reflection you get "more" quantifiers in your sentence, and you never manage to "catch your tail"). So these are meaningful sentences in the language of arithmetic which provide counterexamples to the claim in question.

Comment: Thanks. I won't profess to fully understand your answer yet but it sounds like we're up against the inability of Peano to prove its own consistency here. Is proving untrue statements equivalent to being inconsistent?

Comment: @RobertFrost Re: your last sentence, the answer is no - PA + "PA is inconsistent" is consistent, assuming PA is consistent, even though (assuming PA is consistent) "PA is inconsistent" is false. And the soundness issue is indeed a rather subtle side effect of (the ideas around) PA not proving its own consistency.

Comment: ok thanks. Looks like understanding soundness will have to go in the laterbase.

Comment: A little more precisely, what are *only true things*, in *"these roughly assert that PA proves only true things"*?  What I know is that you probably aren't declaring there to be absolute truth - my best guess is you're mean not contradicted by *something*.  Where *something* is probably PA or any consistent model of PA maybe?